# Caching all scripts in web app

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, caching, getscript

I have a very large web app with over 100 scripts in total. Currently when you visit a page in the app it will load the scripts it needs for that app.

The problem is, is that some pages have a lot of complex scripts which can mean the page takes several seconds to load.

One way to get around this that I'm using is to use JQuery's $.getscript to load scripts when a user clicks a button to view the next section on that page (where content is dynamically added and removed from the DOM).

This works OK and has sped up my pages quite a lot.

I was reading a few other posts which reminded me of the fact that the browser caches scripts.

My question is would it be a lot better to load every single script in my app the moment after the user logs in? Obviously this would mean that first page after login takes a while to load where I would present them with a "Loading" spinner or something.

Would this speed up my app a lot if I leverage browser caching abilities?

---

This is how I load scripts now.

In my view I have a "JS" array which each controller pushes the needed scripts for that page onto:

```
class Activity extends Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->view->js = array(
            'Activity2/js/activity.js',
            'Activity2/js/customer.js',
            'Activity2/js/selling.js',
            'Activity2/js/buying.js',
...
```

That array is then looped through and output in the footer:

```
<?PHP
if(isset($this->js)) {
  foreach($this->js as $js) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . WROOT . Vs . $js . '"></script>';
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes, of course. Not necessarily in one go, but load whatever scripts each page requires on that page itself. First time will be slow, but subsequent hits will be fast.

Comment: @abhitalks Unfortunately this hasn't been the case. When I had everything load that was specific to a page, the page was very slow no matter how many times you refreshed or came back to it.

Comment: How are you loading the scripts? `script` tag?

Comment: sounds like you need conditionally loading, check out [yepnopejs](http://yepnopejs.com/)...afaik code optimization goes like this: write less/better code, get faster machine/internet, load only what you need and only do what you need ;)

Comment: That should cache them. What do you see in 'developer tools > network'. Does it say `Status Code:200 OK (from cache)` on the scripts?

Comment: @abhitalks I'm getting status 304 for all my scripts, things like CSS and images get 200.

Comment: @imperium2335 We are getting closer. 304 means the browser is going to the server and then gets a 'no' response to whether the file has changed since last access. So, although it won't re-download the resource, it still goes to the server and back. This coupled with resolution time will contribute to the slowness. Ideal would be 200(cache). This requires you to set far-future expiry on your resources. Hope that helps.

Comment: @abhitalks How do I set far-future expiry on my files?

Comment: @imperium2335 I don't know much about apache (which I presume you are using as your server). However, you can refer to this: http://cjohansen.no/en/apache/using_a_far_future_expires_header and/or google it, you will find many resources.

Comment: @abhitalks I've added <FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpe?g|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</FilesMatch>
But I still get 304.

Comment: @imperium2335 As I said I don't know apache, which is the first reason I didn't post an answer but only commented. Moreover, this warrants a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that downloading 100 x 1k files is slower than downloading a "1 x 100kb" file.
What about a php script that generate a single js instead of having 100 script tags in your page?

Think at that poor browser that have to check if 100 or more files are cached or not ;)

This answer is specific for your question where you wrote about 100 js files and the way you are loading. You should also have a look at AMD and require.js technologies.

D.